# Jquery loop: iterate siblings by four, then re-start from beginning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Q:** How do I create a loop to show four `div` at time, that are children of `#reviewswidget`? Once slideshow hits end of children, it needs to return to the first four divs.

```
<div id="reviewswidget">
    <div class="reviewtitle">title 1 goes here</div>
    <div class="reviewrating">rating 1 goes here</div>
    <div class="reviewreview"> review 1 goes here</div>
    <div class="reviewauthor">author 1 goes here</div>
    <div class="reviewtitle">title 2 goes here</div>
    <div class="reviewrating">rating 2 goes here</div>
    <div class="reviewreview"> review 2 goes here</div>
    <div class="reviewauthor">author 2 goes here</div>
</div>
```

**My Attempt:**

```
jQuery(function () {
        jQuery('#reviewswidget div').hide().slice(0, 4).show();
        setInterval(function () {
            jQuery('#reviewswidget div').filter(':visible').fadeOut(function () {
                self.setSliceIteration(4);
                self.setSliceTotal(jQuery('#reviewswidget div').length);
                if (self.getSlice() === 0 && self.getSlice() === '') {
                    jQuery('#reviewswidget div').hide().nextAll().slice(self.getSlice()).show();
                    self.setSlice(self.getSliceIteration() + self.getSlice());             
                }
                if (self.getSlice() < self.getSliceTotal()) {
                    $(this).nextAll().slice(self.getSlice()).show();
                    self.setSlice(self.getSliceIteration() + self.getSlice());
                }
                if (self.getSlice() < self.getSliceTotal()) {                   
                }
            });
        }, 3000);
    });
```

**Full Code:** http://jsfiddle.net/Q3jaf/1/

Comment: Why not put 4 divs into a parent div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var $chidlren = $('#reviewswidget').children().slice(4).hide();
setInterval(function(){
    $('#reviewswidget').children().slice(0, 4).hide().appendTo('#reviewswidget')
    $('#reviewswidget').children().slice(0, 4).show()
}, 1000)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HyC46/)

Comment: How would I implement a single fadein and fadeout transition? Appendto just shifts it down. http://jsfiddle.net/Q3jaf/2/

Comment: If I wanted to add a delay for x amount of seconds after fade in, then perform the fade out how would I do it in this example?

Comment: @DavidEugenePeterson try http://jsfiddle.net/QHe3t/3/ - increase the `setInterval()` delay